# Android Studio frontend client [running from Device] not connecting to Google AppEngine Backend

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, device

I'm running into issues getting my frontend (being built in Android Studio using Java, running through an android device connected via USB) to connect to a locally hosted app-engine backend (running as a local devserver).

**Errors are as follows:**

Error when attempting to call an API method with:

'apiBld.setRootUrl("http://192.168.0.x:8080/_ah/api/");'

http://pastebin.com/eqHrSLfJ

Error when attempting to call an API method with:

'apiBld.setRootUrl("http://0.0.0.0:8080/_ah/api/");'

http://pastebin.com/s7PMqiyK

-

When its run with *'192.168.0.x:8080'* the emulated version of the code runs fine, the app connects locally and can call API methods. I've tried suggestions from various other related posts, but nothing has solved my issue. In pom.xml Ive also been sure to enable 0.0.0.0 for the port and we're not yet using authentication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that it connects in the emulator, as the avd network address to tunnel to your computer's loopback is 10.0.2.2.

Make sure the server is running by putting the URL in the browser. You may need to change the port to something else if it is already bound (ie: xbmc web server uses 8080 by default) try 8081. Don't forget the 'httpPort' directive in your build.gradle if using android studio.

Comment: Thanks Richard, Ive replied on the reddit post with more details - still havent been able to solve the issue. I cant find any information on this 'httpPort' directive either?

Comment: Update - fixed the issue (finally!)
Think it was a mixture of the port already being in use, and not setting the right IP, along with at times not using wifi on the device.